# Proof Using Contrapositive

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I need help on solving this problem.
Prove that if A x B = {}, then A = {} or B = {}.

(Prove the contrapositive) ( {} = Empty Set )

Answer (score 2):

You want to prove
$$A\times B=\emptyset \Longrightarrow A=\emptyset \mbox{ or } B=\emptyset$$
by contrapositive, that means:
$$A\not=\emptyset \mbox{ and } B\not=\emptyset \Longrightarrow A\times B\not= \emptyset\mbox.$$
This is simply becouse if $A,B$ are not empty, there exist $a\in A$ and $b\in B$, so the element $(a,b)\in A\times B$ which, now, cannot be empty.